# cshtml and cshtml.cs doesn't work after deployment

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a simple ASP.NET Core 3.1 web app with very simple page and its view model which has some code which fires `OnGet`.

- MyPage.cshtml
- MyPage.cshtml.cs

Code:

```
 public class MyPageModel : PageModel
 {
    public void OnGet(string city)
    {
       ...
    }
 }
```

Locally this works fine but after deployment, I cannot access this route. I'm getting a 404 error.

Both of these files `.cshtml` and `.cshtml.cs` have the property `copy to output directory` set to `false`.

Do I need to set this to true in order to be accessible after deployment?

Comment: No. What is the web server? Can you show the csproj and web.config?

Comment: Do _any_ pages work?

Comment: @mjwilis pages accessible through controllers working fine.

Comment: @vernou web server is kestrel

Comment: What is your "deployment" method for kestrel? By "deployment" you mean release compilation? visual studio's publish? What does it mean "after deployment" to you?

Comment: Do you develop on Windows? The site is hosted on Linux? Unlike Windows, Linux is case sensitive. Check the route to your page. (I don't know if this affect ASP.NET Core)